# Magento 2 Product Tabs 100%

Tags: product, magento-2.1, product-attribute

I want change the width from the Product Tabs to 100% width. The problem now is that the tabs are inside the #maincontent and i can't move it to other reference container.
Have anyone a idea how i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved it by moved the tabs inside the page wrapper.

```
<move element="product.info.details" destination="page.wrapper"/>
```